# How to figure out the required headers for a java REST call?

Tags: java, json, rest, http-headers

When testing with the jsonplaceholder.typicode.com site java code does not need to set any headers. Reading the json from a `URLConnection` works fine. However other http endpoints will return a `403 Forbidden` unless a `HttpURLConnection` is used and the `User-Agent` request property is set.

Is there a way other than trial and error to figure out the required headers for a given http endpoint?

Comment: Read the documentation (if it exists), or crib from other client code.

Comment: Fair comment: No documentation on the headers. Other client code added way more headers than required. Hence the question.

Comment: I see :/  Well then the answer to the question is: no.

Comment: Looks like you know what you  are talking about. Post it as an answer and I will accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the HTTP protocol that allows you to observe what headers a particular server is expecting.  You send a request, and the server sends a response, that's all.  (A nice server may, of course, choose to embed a helpful error message in its response.)

So the literal answer to your question is: no, there's no way to determine this beyond trial and error (unless you have access to documentation and/or source code).